# LTPA Formbased authentication with Worklight gives no method handle Failure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight Developer Edition Studio 5.0.5.1 (5.0.5.20130115-0926)
Worklight Consumer Edition Version 5.0.5.1

First question
Are application developed with WL Developer Edition compatible with WL Consumer Edition Server.

Second Question:
I am using the Module 21 Formbased authentication and modified the realm in the authentication handler and added the customer security test that references the LTPA realm to the authentication config xml (file in installedApp folder).

I am getting no method to handleFailure when we access the method that requires security in the application.

03-01 18:53:32.870: E/Web Console(870): Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'handleFailure' at file:///data/data/com.FormBasedAuthentication/files/www/default/wlclient/js/worklight.js:1482

Answer (score 1):

Yes, applications developed with Developer Edition are compatible with Consumer Edition.

Comment: For your second question, are you talking about submitFailure?